# Hide the scroll bar, but it continue working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I'm trying to hide the vertical bar of a scrollpane, but I want that it continues scrolling vertically. This is my code:

```
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(arbol);
        scroll.setBounds(35,40, 230, 530);
        scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll.setBorder(null);
        scroll.setOpaque(false);
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setBorder(null);
        scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        JLabel sep=new JLabel(Imagen("SeparaV.png"));
        sep.setSize(scroll.getSize());
        sep.setLocation(-17, 0);
        sep.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        scroll.add(sep);
        Frame.add(scroll);
```

For me it is good, if it only shows the arrows. So this is what I need:

[image]

Comment: `for me is good if only show the arrows` - I think that not, not nice, remove Increase/DecreaseButton by to setPreferredSize to (0, 0) and then to override Thumb with transparency, a few times here, e.i.

Comment: The arrows are part of the scroll bar...

Answer (score 0):

> for me is good if only show the arrows

I assume you mean you don't want to see the bar in the middle that is used to drag the scrollbar. If so then you can use the default Actions of the scrollbar to create a simple panel with only the arrow buttons:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ScrollPaneSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public ScrollPaneSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        JTable table = new JTable(50, 5);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(scrollPane);
        JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();

        JPanel east = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

        BasicArrowButton north = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.NORTH);
        north.setAction( new ActionMapAction("", vertical, "negativeUnitIncrement") );
        east.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        BasicArrowButton south = new BasicArrowButton(BasicArrowButton.SOUTH);
        south.setAction( new ActionMapAction("", vertical, "positiveUnitIncrement") );
        east.add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ScrollPaneSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new ScrollPaneSSCCE());
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You will need to check out [Action Map Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) to understand how this works.